# How to choose Url based on language?

Tags: java, android

I want to load "english.JSON" if the phone is in English, "french.Json" if the phone is in French, and how can I do it?

Or load url in different language.

Comment: `Locale` is the class you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can get selected language using this **Kotlin code**:

```
val language = Locale.getDefault().language

val file = when (language) {
    "en" -> "english.json"
    "fr" -> "french.json"
    else -> null
}
```

or **Java code**:

```
String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();

String file = null;

switch (language) {
    case "en":
        file = "english.json";
        break;
    case "fr":
        file = "french.json";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Named your files like this example : `(country_en.json,country_fr.json ...)`

***JAVA Code:***

```
String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
String file= "country_"+language +".json";
```